EF Core Npgsql mapping object (T type) with list of objects (T2 type) with single T type object
Im making an app that implement custom permissions system. I have Users and Groups. Each user can be in many groups and each group can have many users. Users and Groups have permissions to many object/functionalities in the app. Each object has entity "Permissions" that define which user/group has a specific privileges. I want "Permissions" to be stored in single column as a json with Npgsql and postgres database.
The problem is that i want groups also to be managable so it also has entity permission. So, "group" has object "permissions" that has list of objects and list of objects with specified permissions. To make everything clear, I am placing the objects below:
User:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string? DisplayName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Token> Tokens { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

Group:
public class ApplicationGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
}

Permissions:
public class Permissions
{
    public List<UserPermissions> UserPermissions { get; set; }
    public List<GroupPermissions> GroupPermissions { get; set; }
}

UserPermissions:
public class UserPermissions
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public List<Common.Helpers.Enums.Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
}

GroupPermissions:
public class GroupPermissions
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupId))]
    public ApplicationGroup Group { get; set; }

    public List<Common.Helpers.Enums.Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
}

And the last, modelBuilder for group:
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>()
    .OwnsOne(c => c.Permissions, d =>
    {
        d.ToJson();
        d.OwnsMany(d => d.UserPermissions);
        d.OwnsMany(d => d.GroupPermissions);
    });

So, when im trying to create migration i got this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'AdminContext'. The exception 'Entity type 'ApplicationGroup.Permissions#Permissions.GroupPermissions#GroupPermissions' is mapped to JSON and has a navigation to a regular entity which is not the owner.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I tried create custom navigation, mark group with foreign key groupid, create conversion for group but nothing works just fine. Anyone can help?
